# select one element from list of values in column dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

all,
My input:

```
logs = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['A','B','C','D'],'bar':[[12,13,14],[10,9,11],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] })
```

I trying extract specific element from column where data is list of values.
For example I need extract from column `bar` where first row `A`, first value `12` in list of `[12,13,14]`. And in continue run some loop per all list to extract and assign each element of list in new values and do it over all dataframe.
So my code:

```
logs.iloc[0:1,1].values[0]
```

And I **expect** get `12`, but it doesn't happen

Comment: Just take the first item using `[0]`, `logs.iloc[0:1,1].values[0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you can use it and do something like it